# Cannot connect with Active Directory to reset password

Tags: java, ssl, active-directory, ssl-certificate

I am totally new to this field and not much experienced in java too. I was assigned this task and I could connect in simple mode as admin and retrieve info, but couldnot reset password. I found in many sites that I have to use ssl for that, but couldnt successfully do that as I get a

"simple bind failed"

error I post my code below of what I did and also the codes I commented out(which I tried earlier). Please please please help. I couldnt solve the problem from any source I received. I used a certificate copied from server into my keystore. Is this the right way to use that?? If i remove the ssl part

```
 env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL,"ssl");
```

I get a handshake exception

```
Problem with TLS: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed


public class ActiveDirectory {
private DirContext ctx;

public boolean connect(String username,String password){
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
//      Properties env=new Properties();
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL,"ssl");
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://192.168.1.199:389");
    env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");

    // The value of Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL must be the logon username
    // with the domain name
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username+"@xxxx.net");

    // The value of the Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS should be the user's
    // password
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    try {
        // Authenticate the logon user
        ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env,null);
        return true;
    }catch(NamingException e){
        System.out.println("Error in connecting : " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

}


public boolean changePasswordAdmin(String userName,String newPassword){
    try {

        //set password is a ldap modfy operation
        //Secure the session with TLS

        StartTlsResponse tls = (StartTlsResponse)((LdapContext) ctx).extendedOperation(new StartTlsRequest());
        tls.negotiate();

        //set password is a ldap modfy operation
        ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];

        //Replace the "unicdodePwd" attribute with a new value
        //Password must be both Unicode and a quoted string
        String newQuotedPassword = "\"" + newPassword + "\"";
        byte[] newUnicodePassword = newQuotedPassword.getBytes("UTF-16LE");

        mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", newUnicodePassword));

        // Perform the update
        ctx.modifyAttributes(userName, mods);

        System.out.println("Reset Password for: " + userName);
        tls.close();
        ctx.close();
        return true;
    } 
    catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem resetting password: " + e);
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem encoding password: " + e);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem with TLS: " + e);
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws NamingException {
    Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider()); 
    // the keystore that holds trusted root certificates 
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\keystore.jks"); 
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "****"); 
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\keystore.jks"); 
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "****"); 


    ActiveDirectory d= new ActiveDirectory();
    d.connect("Administrator", "Group&Team2");
    System.out.println(d.fetchData("MG"));
    System.out.println(d.changePasswordAdmin("CN=Manager MG. Manager,OU=Manager,DC=xxxxx,DC=net", "Abcd@10"));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your active directory doesn't have a valid certificate.

This is probably the case because the root certificate wasn't imported in Java.

[Here](http://www.martin-probst.com/blog/2008/03/14/installing-importing-a-root-certificate-in-java/) is a small tutorial how to import certificates into java.

Comment: Errrr... Actually I activated the active directory certificate services from the server(win 2008) adn copied the certificate, added it to cacerts in jre\lib\security???

Comment: Did you add the certificate to the keystore?

Comment: # convert:
openssl x509 -in a-cert-globaltrust.crt -out a-cert-globaltrust.pem -outform PEM
can you please tell me what does this mean?? I want to have openssl in my system right.. (MD5) (SHA1) (PGP sign) three are there

Comment: Did you use the `keytool` or did you not?

Comment: yes I did.... keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file xxxx.crt -keystore keystore.jks

Comment: also to cacerts. checked with both

Comment: But is that not the right certificate to use?? I am sorry but my doubts may seem silly, may be due to that I dont find any answers..